# Windows PE batch script runs but does not update file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch script that is located on a usb floppy drive (A:) called POSTcounter, which is autoexecuted by a modified (startnet.cmd) file that is in the Windows PE image. The script is simply incrementing a value that is the number of posts and writes the number to a txt file saved on the floppy drive. This script runs fine in windows environment command prompt and saves the txt file. However when the script is autoexecuted in WinPE the script runs but the txt file does not get updated.

startnet.cmd includes:

wpeinit

A:\POSTcounter.cmd

POSTcounter.cmd includes:

```
@echo off

echo. This script is counting the # of POSTs.
echo.                                        


call:myPOSTTest

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (TEST.txt)  do echo POST# %%x


echo.&pause&goto:eof


::--------------------------------------------------------
::-- Function section starts below here
::--------------------------------------------------------
-- 
:myPOSTTest    - here starts my function identified by its label

cd "A:\"

if not exist TEST.txt >TEST.txt echo 0

for /f %%x in (TEST.txt) do (

set /a var=%%x+1

)


>TEST.txt echo %var%

goto:eof
```

Comment: Are we sure it's still the A: drive in the PE environment.  Maybe a better For loop is needed `for %%i in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%i:\POSTcounter.cmd set VAR=%%i:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cd` function does not change drives by default.  So this line:

```
cd "A:\"
```

doesn't do anything useful.  Try

```
cd /d a:\
```

instead.